# chef-dk install on windows

Tags: windows, chef-infra, chefdk

I'm having problems following the [learn chef tutorials](https://learn.chef.io/manage-a-node/windows/get-set-up/) on the chef site.  I am upto managing a windows node.

I've downloaded and installed chef-dk and trying to get the commands to work.  Chef verify fails and any chef commands don't work.  Rebooted server to see if that made a difference related to the paths but no joy.

On win7 im unable to get into the c:\opscode folder.

Thought it may be related to the OS so tried it on Win 2012 server with the same issues.

Where am I going wrong as really liking the sound of Chef and itching to get it up and running on our environments.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you do see in terms of folder structure.

Comment: All I can see is c:\opscode and on Windows cannot get into the folder (despite being admin)

Comment: i can go into the folder from the command line but the directory listing is denied.

Comment: on the desktop there is a chef shortcut and when i cut and paste the properties of the powershell that is run:  PS C:\> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\opscode\ch
efdk\bin\start-chefdk.ps1
The argument 'C:\opscode\chefdk\bin\start-chefdk.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an exis
ting '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.

Comment: Do you have any funky group policy rules enabled?

Comment: No, nowt. Full admin rights on my machine. Just tried it on my own win 10 laptop and it's fine. Possibly powershell execution policy related?